# Is "taken for granted" passive voice? If so, how should I correct it?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice

Original sentence:

> Maya Angelou uses imagery to convey that freedom should not be taken for granted.

I thought of an alternative to use like this, but I'm afraid that it might seem awkward:

> Maya Angelou uses imagery to convey that one should not take freedom for granted.

Is the original sentence grammatically correct? If not, would the second one be okay, or is there something better that I should use?

Comment: Original is grammatically correct and sounds perfectly natural. Your alternative is also correct and not too awkward, but not as idiomatic imo.

Comment: The passive voice is always grammatically (syntactically) correct. Choosing when to deploy it is a matter of style. You almost answered your own question... Go with your passive voice version.